If I am under contract not to form a contract, will courts enforce this?
Say Jimothy really hates Horatia. I sign a contract with Jimothy promising never to contract with Horatia, in exchange for $200.00. Then I visit a blog and read three posts.
But wait! That blog has a "Terms of Service" link on it, which specifies that opening any blog post is how I indicate my consent to a contract, which limits the liability of the blog owner and has me promise not to repost any dank memes. And the blog belongs to Horatia!
Have I formed a contract with Horatia, and violated my existing contract with Jimothy? Or, being already obligated not to form a contract with Horatia, would my conduct of clicking on blog posts somehow not count as indicating assent, since I am obligated not to assent to the offered contract and therefore legally don't?
If I have formed a contract with Horatia, can Jimothy sue to have it voided under some notion of compelling performance of my contract with them?

Sounds like an illegal restraint of trade
In general, a contract that limits a person’s ability to form other contracts is unenforceable unless there is a clear imperative to that restriction. For example, a contract from one film studio preventing you from contracting with another film studio for a limited time is probably fine. One that prohibits you from contracting with a given motor mechanic probably isn’t.
So, the most likely outcome is that the contract with Jimothy because he “really hates Horatia” is probably void.
Notwithstanding …
If the original contract is valid and if there is a contract with Horatia, Jimothy can successfully sue.
However, there probably isn’t a contract with Horatia because, a) unless the agreement is a click wrap and b) Horatia‘s involvement is clearly apparent then a) there isn’t a contract or b) there is no intention to form a contract with Horatia.
